# Can I add a file and burn an .iso at once?

Tags: windows-xp, ubuntu, dvd, iso-image, authoring

I just downloaded a Windows 7 iso from MSDNAA at school and they gave me a personal key. I'd like to add a file with my key onto the disc, but it has to remain bootable.

Is there a really simple way to do this, or one that doesn't require some shareware?

I'm using XP right now, or any solution under ubuntu is fine.

Comment: write the key with a felt-tip pen on the disk.

Comment: Problem is that the disk is in the drive when you need to type it in.
Also with my bad writing I have trouble reading what I wrote on the disk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

extract the ISO with **[7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)**, add your file then use **[vLite](http://www.vlite.net/)** to create a new installation DVD.

of course you may use vLite and your license key to create an [unattended](http://www.vlite.net/help/unattended.html) installation disc (then you wouldn't need the key at all :)

note: for legal reasons, later versions of vLite come without the required WIM filter, which is part of WAIK (Windows Automated Installation Kit), WAIK is a [free download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=C7D4BC6D-15F3-4284-9123-679830D629F2&displaylang=en) but fairly big in size (993 MB).

Comment: i assume you mean 993 MB?

Comment: you assume correctly, edited now :)

Comment: I recommed using nlite instead as it has more options and no need to download additional files

Comment: except, nLite only works for 2k/xp, for Vista/7 you'll need vLite. :)